# How to resize & create exfat partitions on SDCARD

Tags: partitioning, sd-card, resize, exfat

I have an external 64Gb SDCard which I formate to exfat (default) in my smartphone, but I want to reformat it to create 4 x 16Gb exfat partitions using my PC.  Gparted and KDE Partition Manager do not resize exfat.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Gparted and KDE Partition Manager do not resize exfat because there are no (command line) tools to resize exfat.

The easiest thing you can do is to backup all data from your exfat partition and copy it back later after repartitioning.

Comment: you should backup your data anyway before manipulating partitions!!!

Comment: I wouldn't say before manipulating partitions. You should just backup your data regularly. Partitioning tools are quite safe unless your filesystems are badly damaged. But then it might be already too late for backup...

Comment: well, you are right! - i meant you should do a **additional backup right before** manipulating partitions!!!